# How do I change camelcase to snakecase in Grape params

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

In my Grape endpoint I have a required param called `user_type`. On the other hand, my public API declares this param as `userType`, i.e. camel case. Is there a way to changes this?

```
 module MyAPI
      module V1
        class SignUp < Grape::API
          desc 'Create new user account'
          params do
           requires :email, type: String
           requires :password, type: String
           requires :user_type, type: String
          end
          post :sign_up do
            {}
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: FYI, user_type is referred to as snake case; userType is referred to as lower camel case.

Comment: @bigtunacan thanks, I mixed it up.

Comment: Checkout this [Blog Post](https://github.com/jrhe/grape-active_model_serializers) for a method that very nicely converts lowerCamelCase to snake_case. This way you can leave your public API untouched and handle the key conversion in the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly, but it will do the trick so you could just pop it into a method.

```
def sym_to_lower_camel(sym)
  sym.to_s.split('_').map{|x| x.capitalize}.join.sub(/^./, sym.to_s[0].downcase)
end
```